# Scala getting field and type of field of a case class

Tags: scala, reflection, pattern-matching, match, case-class

So I'm trying to get the field and their types in a case class. At the moment I am doing it like so

```
typeOf[CaseClass].members.filter(!_.isMethod).foreach{
   x =>
     x.typeSignature match {
        case _:TypeOfFieldInCaseClass => do something
        case _:AnotherTypeOfFieldInCaseClass => do something
     }
}
```

the problem is `x.typeSignature` is of type `reflect.runtime.universe.Type` which cannot match on any of the types that reside in the case class. Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 15):

Let's say you have the following case class defined:

```
case class CaseClass(i: Int, s: String)
```

with pattern matching you can achieve what you want with the following:

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

typeOf[CaseClass].members.filter(!_.isMethod).map(_.typeSignature).foreach {
  case t if t == typeOf[Int] => print("i")
  case s if s == typeOf[String] => print("s")
}
```

### Why?

So why the first attempt does not work?

That's because in your code you are using type-patterns. Type patterns check the type of subject-to-match - which is a type signature in this case - at runtime. So by using `_: Int` we are asking for a type check at runtime against each type signature of non-method members of `CaseClass`.

But in this case what we need is a value match.

Let's take a closer look (using Scala REPL):

```
scala> case class CaseClass(i: Int, s: String)
defined class CaseClass

scala> typeOf[CaseClass]
res1: reflect.runtime.universe.Type = CaseClass

scala> typeOf[CaseClass].members
res2: reflect.runtime.universe.MemberScope = Scopes(method equals, method toString, ..)

scala> typeOf[CaseClass].members.filter(!_.isMethod)
res4: Iterable[reflect.runtime.universe.Symbol] = SynchronizedOps(value s, value i)

scala> typeOf[CaseClass].members.filter(!_.isMethod).map(_.typeSignature)
res5: Iterable[reflect.runtime.universe.Type] = List(String, scala.Int)
```

So what we want to match is of type `reflect.runtime.universe.Type`. Note that in the last line, `String` and `scala.Int` are just string representations of these types not their actual type!

So we need to match them against different values of this type which we can easily get with `typeOf[Int]` and `typeOf[String]`.

### A bit more on pattern matching in Scala

You may want to make the code more concise by using the following code:

```
typeOf[CaseClass].members.withFilter(!_.isMethod).map(_.typeSignature).foreach {
  case typeOf[Int] => print("i")    // Won't Compile!
  case typeOf[Int] => print("s")    // Won't Compile
}
```

But this give you the following compile error:

```
not found: type typeOf
```

Again this is because here we need to match against a variable name beginning with an uppercase letter. So the following works:

```
val T = typeOf[Int]
val S = typeOf[String]

typeOf[CaseClass].members.withFilter(!_.isMethod).map(_.typeSignature).foreach {
  case T => print("i")
  case S => print("s")
}
```

For more details on pattern matching, refer to [Programming in Scala](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0981531644). You will find a detailed explanation of pattern matching there.

Comment: How does this change if the fields are Options?. If the fields are options the above method doesn't work and results in a match error.

Comment: In that case you need an extra guard (extra `case`) otherwise you will get a `MatchError`.

Comment: Anyway this is an answer to what you asked in the question but I'd suggest reviewing your requirements and considering other alternatives. I would say that in most cases you can achieve the same functionality without reflection, unless you are writing a a framework.